# как сделать резиновый треугольнику снизу блока?

Tags: css

Никак не могу решить проблему с треугольником снизу.
нужно вот так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.variant-chistki {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.variant-row {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  column-gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.variant-left {
  width: 50%;
  height: fit-content;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  text-align: left;
}

.variant-right {
  width: 50%;
  height: fit-content;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  text-align: left;
}

.foto {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 230px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.foto img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  margin: 5px auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgb(0 0 0);
}

.variant-right::after {
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -38px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #68B04D;
}

.variant-right-1 {
  background: #68B04D;
  width: 100%;
  height: 327px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.variant__title {
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.variant__text {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="variant-chistki">
  <div class="variant-row">

    <div class="variant-left">
      <div class="foto">
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
          alt="Спил дерева с Авто вышки">
      </div>
      <div class="variant__title">Спил дерева с Авто вышки</div>
      <div class="variant__text">Данный способ позволяет удалить дерево или ветки там, где использование автовышки невозможно. Арбарист оснащен специальным снаряжением, которое позволяет ему быстро залезть к необходимому месту среза ствола или ветки.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="variant-right">
      <div class="variant-right-1"></div>
      <div class="foto">
        <img src="https://65.img.avito.st/image/1/1.8O2zvba6XASFFJ4B34q0yFoeWgAHnlTGAh5YDA8WXg.MmcQ850dtMPiU2LpsyrLO_qXCTBSkeQ7L3JfW6YHRFo" alt="Спил дерева альпинистами">
      </div>
      <div class="variant__title">Спил дерева альпинистом</div>
      <div class="variant__text">Данный способ позволяет удалить дерево или ветки там, где использование автовышки невозможно. Арбарист оснащен специальным снаряжением, которое позволяет ему быстро залезть к необходимому месту среза ствола или ветки.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `clip-pth - css` попробуй... `svg`...

Comment: Спасибо! это действительно отлично сработало! Не знал про это свойство!

Answer (score 0):

.variant-left я переделал, а правый оставил по старому.

```css
.variant-chistki {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.variant-row {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  column-gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.variant-left {
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: fit-content;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
  padding: 1px 15px 40px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.variant-left:before {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -300vh;
    height: 300vh;
    width: 100%;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    transform: skewY(20deg);
}
.variant-left:after {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -300vh;
    height: 300vh;
    width: 100%;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    transform: skewY(-20deg);
}
.variant-left .foto {
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
}
.variant-left .foto:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% + 40px);
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -20px;
  background: white;
}
.variant-left .foto img {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}
.variant-left a {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: max-content;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px auto 0;
}

.variant-right {
  width: 50%;
  height: fit-content;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  text-align: left;
}

.foto {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 230px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.foto img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  margin: 5px auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgb(0 0 0);
}

.variant-right::after {
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -38px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #68B04D;
}

.variant-right-1 {
  background: #68B04D;
  width: 100%;
  height: 327px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.variant__title {
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.variant__text {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="variant-chistki">
  <div class="variant-row">

    <div class="variant-left">
      <div class="foto">
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAoHCBQVFBgUFRQYGRgaGxsbGhsbGxsaGhwdHBsaHhoZGhsbIC0kGx0pIhsaJTcmKS4wNDQ0GyM5PzkyPi0yNDABCwsLEA8QHRISHTIjJCkyMDIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMDIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjAyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMP/AABEIAMIBAwMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAABBQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFAAEDBAYCB//EAEEQAAIBAwIDBgQDBgQFBAMAAAECEQADIRIxBEFRBRMiYXGBBjKRoUKx8CNScsHR4RQzYvEkQ4KishVjksKTs+L/xAAZAQADAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgMBBAX/xAAkEQACAgICAwADAAMAAAAAAAAAAQIRAzEhQQQSURMiYRQykf/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8At3wsQekiB06dKrDsq2fw6TM+Hwn0JWCfTarz2gSCRkbeXpUgFd1EbKDdmgiO8cehA/lFQXOyCCz27zKSIIdUdGxHjEA+4M4osTVN+LBMKGJ2K7b+ZxWNI22C14qLnd3wFcwFuKZtt5GcK2MTuRiuX4FAGZRBgyTgr0Anc+R+1XWmAr2+8L48RGgkHpyiT54queBuWwFtXAmokslxdVuZEaDnSPKTsKRoLErsg0MTpgNBEFdsAlW1dQZpKiFtVtXbrHd6Z6yYj1Bpl7cuWyUv21kYLoZtzy1mPAf7YFX73C6yGY+LBUW/DA87kyR6RNbwwsDcVwV5ZChTqyqll3kEsuiII3zINNw/E3GuyXRmAkTGhpgGLkgEwoEQIJPSiN3sy2fAzRAGXlyZ2Go5A2wOu9VT2YhZ5CqsAY7xBidQAXEE7+YpXFmpk93jLjyotIZkYdsxzIKYI6Hb0zQvtoXEQEWwp0G3OpWiRKkEwZlfP5j1rjiOGvWkL20L2wdQY6wySInxAM5z80SIgkg4r8Txoa06Mml7gXJGpdGJdG1csGRMmBSt/Qo41rdAUErbZFRnYaAwWBpmNHL5jnOOobieH4VbDW2Wyr6SUdJZ2IiAdMkMSR5EVK3bFxeH/wCHVSEtrqaBpQKBCy3zvjUQBAJ8qL8N8P2Lds3bwLnTrZz8xMSY0/KDMAD3OwGJXo2zE2+Lv2wpIuaT4RIYA4+RQcHB286ftHtJ7mLoOpTABGkrtIiMY5HrNXu0kZS9u45OmHVVBfQTMJ3kypExqMjnFWmLW7fd8YtxULagzItzI/ddR4SZAO8mp10MZwKTcwSRgjVuBGxE7+nWu1bIiAeU77dNv9qi4oqtwhH1oG8LQRIPMg5n+lcTPKkNCSYK6o+YT7yPpt9K7tcY9tbttdGm4CC2SVHikAcjJqg5aILHEEefv7VfI70rC7gS0ZMdP60t1ybst8A7sLVlmASTiRpycliNzPKtenF2wVS20qqFFOksGYzr0gDxEBR5CTQPsK1ch7dpFQyNdzGIwQp3kxOPqN61fC8EEWVgt+8dzH4egXyHvJk10YourEm+iAcHcaGclBAGDNyM5JGFOThfrV2xYVRgbc4j3jkak73wkxkbg8vWu0cHb9enlXQkhLK97h9mXkZK8iIMwORj8hTWkVtZUyGiDJiNCxz866fiQmrUYjb+X5j71TF1VYwDpuSYnAeJnykCY5H1osCzw7jaI2Pl4uQ/XKuNMXiTP+Xjc/iz/wDX6molvwQsAsEG2wO4H+1QdsPc0ILbgO7lA0GYdTqIHkADPkKxvgKKXF3e/vG1a+Q4d9tRWAy22MxggEgTNVeL4Vbl9LAC9zZBe5AMc4SdwNvXNR8ZxK8KRbQa9CkEkwSzEY6gwo25HzxX4dmgWyWJutquBRnSNwfLZd4gmoTyJbHUG9BvspGukXVUIsabeofJb6Iv7zRJY+QzFELnBIcsgJMZLHl02A+1NZt3WHzBRsArqSOmWEfQVxx/DtbTvGaQoOHh5MYGFAyRHvWLyI6HeGWypxHGWLbFO7GI+4nr50q4t9mhgGdrZY5O+/THTb2pUv8AkRD8Mg/T0op67TnOLi43/wBuYxVe9MAAAZwIDBp5AEb+tTPcaYUZ85A9ZrtLe3M8yf5dBWMChbsnLOpk7kECB0AWB0ydzUjKTClmOPl3IG0swE+UT9qtokdT0nYV0ojHM/eijbK68KukoBCxGkRkc9XLPT86ocKe5uHhzlG8duTJA/Emd43HlRN7uidyB+7JI6zHKh3aV23cVfEVbDowXUwYbEaT9QeU0svpqLZdD4vkA5mV9vXl5ZjJx2iAgMwhZlV8/wB5h1HTlk77DOz+0wSEvB++GdJGlfJ01QIPU5FW775ZbitpPiGjxZGTJUSrbH61qkqCibj2CqXLsqrklTEZn+WKx9zs7Wj3rdsQRKWzJZPxagDIeQZZf9RIyKs3nuX2ThkI0swcnUdXdhtn5Bok4nJj0N3bQto7EaERQxIJDKFWAEjEkADPTbNTf7M1cAS+6X7duzYWDegkD8KiO+1dBy8yRRrtziCqJaQS7uqr4ZC6ZYE45aJjOAYmgPw/c7u/eV0W2zot1CsnSsg6eeBqkjOQ3SinD3+8L3yraLc92G/FqSHYjkSNMTsPWhPgGTdi8Mi2gAAS+oMRnUJ0kt1LZb1Y1Zbhiq92H8BwUI1oFgeFZyBON4g8qrpd4fh+GQ3GAOgQP+Yxj8PM+u1Zw8bxvG6ksBltDEzpGP3n5nyUUNpIAV8WcFbs3VW2mkMpJGsupzAIB8Sg9D0xQgbVtOF+ARvdvtJ/cUR7l9/pWX7U4A2Lr2mM6Ig7AggFWjlgiozg1zQyY9gTkgeQnHvV3spfEIjOB0zMc96H8KoO/L+xH5GiKWhIIGQRHoDgn8vaoyKI03wm57xxz0kkHyYQfP5iK1MEZkR6f3rHdhcWtq6WuE+JSOsklSPM+1aXv7zRFtUBxNwyR08Cnn5sN66sMv1JTX7Fm7ggjrpJHnt65jHnVe9dKqSIwGhyIXmYJO30INRv2TqnvLjtPJSLa/QCfvVfjOyn0gLcusuAbbPgjpqjHuYqtv4LwM2nUWd5BA2O+cAczMk45e1Q9q8TFtioeTDAQUA0kE6S0ZgHYc9s0/ApbDADUroNLTqBZRs0E8oG2N6tds24tMSQ0DGoCQeUEefIzS9B2UGvMGRCgI0tHiUDZcySACYONzB3qlxPahW5MHVbTu1U5K3GnUx8gAPtQ/gu1BbTx20uCQTrB/DJZcHY/LFUX4kwzbsQSTvp8pO9Qlk+FFEjRy9wsQWOox/qbGSfLOa1PY3BMuSNTMQSVIOenp70G7MtKFXHiO5zzzsN/StTY4pUTxtsMy2kAHGy5FQkrRWDpha3cCgs63FCrqYlU0geuv1+lB1R+KuajaumynitoAFZoxrYEiZOAJAj7w2eKtuyvfDi2Rqt2gHl9J8LXAR+03kBcUd4bjb7XNdvhngrpAuXEt5JLA+IlgI5aeQqair5KObaB93tJFJU/wCJUjBUgiPL5qVEbn/qpJIXh1nkQ7R76M0qf0j9F9pfBRSininFeocQ1PXVKgDjWNpFRtLDkPP84P8AOptA6CodZYwJxvjHlk8orAOHcwAIgmDGyjryjkPeor3CosM9zT+6cKc76TuZpdzEqEBYz/AAOqj5uWDUYtC2CFM3DJLQBA3DNpjHRREx0BIwCDiX4Vwbd0BzuAEc3Gn8Q0jUDmPp1oQex7twMli5c7td0ultE7G0jMNYMSC0QJjMYOohtqHC+NoVSTLO5wrt5ZYgDYE0TtIEVVnAxJ3J5k+ZyaxxTGszVrjLakgr3V9BPduDlQYi2ww6aZwvPlVjj7nfslhZa2bn7S4MByql9CAGSoIXUwwIjervxBw9u5ZIuLrOyQAX7w/KEPJp57bzWO7I4nikd+Gs21uXElQ4MoknxnODLRJnddjSN06NXJZ7cC8NxKPcYnVbuaoyfEcGJyZOZ6T51A/aPF3kb/D2jbslY1GMqo3DHnG+mfWivAfDR7wXeIfv7k5BzbgKcSdyCB5bYrT3FiOmlhG2+nFCi3/AtGV7I+E7beO+7XH2KGVA8jPibnzA8q1vD2ggCiAB8qqAoUeQFVezxqUFo1jwtsdUYn6g+4NEAoGwiniktCtlduKQTJIjqrDb1Fef/GiK19LqSVuJGrSwUsn7pI8WCuRivQrtrV8xlR+H8J/i6+m3lWU+P2BtWW5hifYrH5wKXIrizY7MZwq5z+tx/OryvJ6kCPz38/60O4Z/F+jV5RnltP69zXEy6CnZbg3EmBLAHMSHldvWK3iDGgiY98cvWNvavMUvaNTyJWCDvmQccpr0TsvijdRrk7udM7AAAR6Hc+tdGB7RPIuy6jjYNPTP51G/EqDBYQOfnHltvXeoNB0+hgn15etM4tncgf8AbjoZ5V0kirxD22Eq4DRqBG4PUHI8iDIMZoN2rxrm2LbDdgRKFQVAmROx2kcq0bvbI06ljaMER0rI/EN209yEMBQZKmFnqBt5HrUsjqI8OWZviuJXxhY3kTsGgTHlXYt6lS2DljJHMRyPuaiv20AbVAEjPPrA8z0rqy90lilttgRsI5fcRiuO7KhcA211OYUdP/EHP5Sa6HeXBcX/AC0QrqTZyZOgHliZ++9VODvqzTdZtaTpVoVVMYIUqc8s9eVF+xbd+7bvBUnvGVywBJBDHIyIXfkfStsw1HZ6W7Ny2LcjV3Rd5ZmMhSVe4ZMSTgmM1q7tm23iKqeW0z5etY3hLLuiFL+sp3YKqqlQFYCJRh8o3zPWjPduCouu4XYG2GZCTsBu6k9JjlNLKh42gp/hk5K3vH8zSqj3E7Wrh9Xg+41YpUg9sH0qeKeK9Y4jkCnArqKQFADRUN532QAnzOR5xVioCDB0482P2FYwK5OhTpYFiYk5k7D0lp+pqe3w6iQfET8xMS55z/Taqty8kxoJRQcgY17GY3AnfIzUXFX0aFU6eUpIzOY05MAeknnFZYFt7EzcYQVUhBzXGWPKT7wB5mo7/E6wEBAZiI5lY3JBx6ZzNQTcgMEc+HIdgp/6S2fZwRBwRQew1xrT3XZksKoUlW8d0r4dFs5CqxwIEmcRvWORtE3E37z8R/h7IUNbtgG42bdvWPG8c7mmAB/FRH4S4cJwlsDnqM/vy7Q/uIPoaFcHwp4bgr4dlS4y3JBIJbUsoJJlmAwPfrWt4dAqIqiAFUAeQAArIrk1nCoZ9NX3j9e1d3AYkCSOXXkakiqfal9rdl7i7qpM9I3PsJNM3SsxK2kVrQNu5JB0vJB5A76TEiJk+5ohaaQD+t6wV7tZzZ7y3fZnM60fTKjkwEbTAz1Fan4Y443bCM5GuDJEQdJyR0O01LFlU/4VzYvR1dl29xPdyXwoklvyrE/E/adu4O4EAkh2YgiIIZVQkY6EkdaK/Efaoa9ZsWlF0lpKq4AZgJRWbYAfNHOsh21ZutcdrwAu6gpRYMAJqBUTOkLGdvOsyyekJBFfh+HAJjUekRB/XrVk6dI8MFfXmMz5VT4TirYhXWJBGpSZzsehjzHOpU4oQ2VMA52ONjBEEGuR3ZZHVy0NLL+8vLqPlM/Stv8ABNxjadZlVYaQfMSRP0z51h7fEqD1BESMn7Uc7H7VNhjAlDBZciYkAgnmM1THL1lbFmrRvXbSQeTED0J5/apooNZ7as3tARoYuoKsIYSCPQ70Ue5pgHmQB1J9PuTXYpJ8kaJK80+Kbnd3bltTgGZ/1NB0+wNar4h+IO61W7WX2ZuSHoOrZ9qxF3gLl0lyYWfmcliT+IwMsZ/OoZZp8IeCaBusu5bcDb+tans7hAbaMJnJJBg8onr71zw/ZCpbAZsjkYVTJmCRmfOakt+IC3b8IHzNMwDyU86jocrXHRrlwXLetpQAaZkqCCwj1HPeprXZHFBbyo7W0QK7Wmcyysy+GVwPmnNSPatpcWB8qZ6sWOJ6wAT71o+ACtcugox120EbDBSAunnz3migIuze07L8Oto23tcRbQFUI0rcXVlkmA0jnvI3xWyv30CEgtphSAc5JGhUnOomBH5UE7X7OS7waA2S3dKx1qGL2wrktpecYyQZnpQbs7jxw19bF+4XtopexdIhQLhaGcblt11ZAzETSSQ0TYd3fOTcKnmq2w4HkG5+tPQv/wBbuHKWCy8mZ7SEjrpdwwHSQMRSpRiSKeK44m6LaM5BIUTA3NTJacx4RnbSSxP2r0JZYxaTeyEccmm0jiKTEASavL2ZeP8Ay294H5mpB2RcPzaB1lh+QmslliuzFBvoGsQBJOKgv6nUqjKGIx1H9NxmjlnsJohrikdAhY+nn9KnX4dtyDLnoQNB+pzHlU35MEMsTMmvCNK6lYgCMH6cwPfeu7dxC8yg0AhEkQJ+Y9Jgew9a2Ldk2wPEkD/W8flVDiLvA2hDPwyquwlTt0E1KXlJaRSOC+zH8fduXS6Wz4MB7gMSB81tGPOJlhOTG+1fj+E4i5ct6LWhbas1u3IOl8KhdduZZRkQnnWhvfE/Ahx/xCkLBARGOekAdPzoLw3b3BNxjXu9uo7SBbdCV1NA1So1ZAEKdqlLyZyTpUXjggpK2Zrt3sm9bAfiLjnVzjVBnMxiCI3jatP8JcW9y2wYkqkKrNucZH8I8P1jlRTtC6FsPcRtYDKTIIABcAgyByPOg9z4msW7eoEMw2RRufJogetS8fypKSUk2vpbyPFi05RaT+GhZgCAee39Kw3xx2463P8ACqdKaQXI3YtnSf8ASBGOc1oeF4e+yM1xzrdg0LGhBpBCCTnedQ3NYftrhFu3703GW4jQ5ZZQkACQy7YjevQnl40cMcPPDTfwoMNS4wR+W8e8VvuLS3Z4MKjFmca01QGYlZnEaVG5I5AjM15/b7O4hTiGT95WDr9s0R4HtdrYdLqC5qUoGAAdVgFhqOdhz2jG9TxzSdBPHKraNB2fwX7S27an0K92Tk6n8BfHzMWDtnkFAqr8UOLz37iJr7q1bRSskhrh1O8jPhXT9TR28up7Vy0+ibVw6fmDAaNKnMaSCTiDsZGRQ7sfN68+WDXWje2nhAUfigGBtnAM1Zrol/TzhlAjGB7VYsopyJWMmfFI5+9EfifsY2LgZR+zcnR4gWUjLI0dOXlQXQd8/wBq55Jp0UTNNcVTa1d2MA84g3AfFgZgGhzs2wJMYMb7Dn71f4G6H4ZwFOpVgmZBGrw45QCB9Ko90w8RMAFJ5YcGD5ZAqceLspLks9iXHd1UKQVYMTmFjI9DK0e4jtxm8YPjZYLAQLan8FsfvEbt7Vn7isoD22KnaBOYJgH2nfrNSpxtuAWkaYLKBuPL1rfZpUhGgp2P2UeIubEID42GNtkB5sefTNXu17ya2S0AQoUY+VdIEKPer3DLxHEqFFv/AA3DxgDDsvIAch5wPeou1+HS1KIsKAuOfLJ6nzq3pURE+QXc7O1aWuMzMWgjYAYx151YtWVSQozqbecQSM89sVYu3gPmKgb5j65qtYvqZhgxJ3H1P8z70tLo04voVLPEmQWgGCojcciN/SjVp3bWpcwtoOunw/uEHHkaqcPp1DWYXmfLrUPCdorbcr4nm0bahBmPlWZO+Bn7VjpGmt4cauETLDUtwGGYTDEDn0xVXsjsnhrt265tZd1e07T+0tqirc0E72y2oFeYIOxmq3CjiLtgKLIFte8GnUxfMND+HSAZiJ50eS21y2iuQvhXRghgVX5gwP5T4ZBpJMaJEfh5VwmlV5A2wxAOYkjIzjyinqa2eHgd5Cv+IarhzzIOrIO48iKalsYOcR25wdoQb9hPQqfsDQi98ednIIW6WPIIhH0MCs9Y7Dsrnu19lA/qfvVzhuAtW/ktovoon671deNLbYjyRWgg3xurR3fB8S/mw0j6k1XPxNxpnu+CtJ5vcBPuFrqlTrxV2zPy/EVrva3abb3rFsf6LZcjy8VCe0b/ABIA73j7rSQItwuJgxp6SN6NXLSkGZ64O3pVI4bVMDTjbkc84III2Fb+CK6F/IwQ/YguCdd26Z/Gxg9fxCR5jmPOq1yxZtuf+Ht6FlQZy1wxAEai5Ax0kxRSLjBwrKgxrfaJzAJHhMZO8COZrhuDRLSPBLkr3cg+BA04B+UEAFjjet/HFaQPJJ9lzsbs90Ju3QiuVChUjSiyTpAAxyk5JIOdgK/xTwi3bfdwNZKlWONABmdXIsYUAZNG799UyxA359NzHQVmPiXtS0jWLhUuUcXFUGFdVIJOckSBBiN8006UWZBtyCHxZbe1wQF0FrpCW1O6liVJJI8AMKZncivOr+LWsxrZxBI8OmDIXETJGK1Hx18TW+LshUV10xKMMKxcSwIMMYwD57Csx2jxbHh7akRplxPOSULL0jTz864FGqO339rb+HofwldJ4a2rvL6AxB+bSSwT18Kge1ZP494l04kW7cAMqs4j5miJPsFqoeONnj7awNKpZsuGEgppTX6EFiZ5EUW+L+yTqHEKoe2W0GSQ65CqyNMsrGd5jHKulNyjVHPKlJ80Zfhu1LltlV1GBCyIIEkwCCNyTU/E8UjsABJAlcDGxhgeh2IqPiOAtlEJJTxAMW8WCf8ATz3jFegfD3A2bXCqECd4bcs2C5Zl3k5jIiMUkYpu9DKUkq2irw/bJbQboKOoYMwGIOxxsMAbEeI1P8Nrb7l7YOo27tyYzILMVcdfCftRzjOER7ZVkDQp04yCBiDyzWNt2/27pYu92ypbK6yVJLAakJ2kEjB6iuhWqbOd1bSC3xb2d3vCuAsugDgDkUyY8imqvMLTx516zwHFXu8Fq/bImRqAgEQTyxGOR515d2nwvdX7lqMJcYD0nw/9pFJk55NgFfh8C5buWg+hmmMYkFW+4FEO1+FC8PpXOkAnqYYEzHP+lBOxbgW4D5ifPzHnBP0rS3CIg5BGfzNc0tl1oztnoD8w2OxysfmabgUNx1sgeJ30z0zuYyI3nyptPdvpn5WZc9DlYn0FaH4W7Gd7wvrCojbzuYyAPQ59a2MbkI3SN6ojnPn/ADrOfEPzt/CtXO0u2rVm8FuXCoW2W0gTJdsEx0CH/wCVZrtTthuILNatkJA8T4BA5jl9JrqySVUSiubKlrhWuM1y5HPcwBAMR706XLVt1OoCAQY85/tXfDdmqwm4WZjJCgkLESNsnlzq1Y4e2hH7NUY4iMxvzz71CmUK1zijchUVtJmSB9p5CtF2dwxEIDoDW9Q0xJIEiSfMVQUUa4DiE7y3kn9mwwMbOZmj17APdmK/cEi44YOw8LQIAEY2FWrFoXLSl5JZF1GSDJGTg4M8xVbsu8vdMIaDcPTmqmrfAf5SRvox5xNTmNE7FkDGpvrNKqnD8deZQ3cMsgHS2mR5HNKloYo0qanr1TkHFPTUzMRyJ+n3rAOXI6wRH6j60L4x9Lr3b6m/dgEL6iYU4MenlVi9w6EgwRPzS2fpM45V1wvCrrLaYC/KCMyZyeZMHn+9WANY4SIZ5JGQmoEKTuxmNb7+I85gCuLxe54Vk/MJJCiYInwgkgTnziiTLzgE0kSDJ32xsB0FFAU7XDGfFLbA5OmBsPEZPWNhvvmgfbKJd4u1a/G7WwwOxRX+VTHTWT6+VaygXA3luXrty4SLvCrcKJjT3boSjzzYk5PLpXN5MqidPjxtszfxDwDPZ4jiSzIspoURpuTcY5BzA14jpWe41T3ti2IMW7SRH74BYGd/nM1r/izikHCpwwDByUBBVlIVBJORBExsTWZbjbacT3uksdcgYlVGAByBiMVGUapL4Vh+1t8KzVdm8ARe4rvkUWmbvFaQ+VJiMEqQsHHTFALl2/3a2NbNZDm4huAh2WfDqG4WZIGN6MdmfESswV7icoJU2n3AkiWQ4k4YbDGaOpf4e8sXVUNGC66T/wDk2PsaSOWUVTRaeCEuYv8A6YR7ZcqCJCnWQuZChifMbVvzYdkTWuhFNsJb/FgqAXYbQB8o6ZJ2Fbh/hy1bui6rOJBAUwy505BgcgRz3o5eSdJEEapP0aPvFVxzi0+SDwzhTa72cPcYE+H0M7jHQHPrFZfhLZX9vA1NcIAJ+YXLhUoQAZAt92Og0CtRxRAUsQTAMCYzFA+z+AC2LBXLlFl1gwSUfJMeHGmPTeutnId9tm5w9p7lgNAB1W8Mi/8AuKCCVA5gQNsb15XxNws5ZyWYmSxySeZJ5mvbbJ1r4lwRkEbg9R9oryn4l+G73Dk3CA1skw67KJ8IcbqYgTt51LImbFlbsGO8O8R/MCtRfT264jpO/oayXYjxcjqp9zitleEzyEsN59/vXJPZ0R0Ae2eFKkNyYR6Mk5+kfQ1b7D7fHCF1ua2B/BtBjBHr1narPasNa/gdSfQ4afY1U4bge+45Tchl7wShEgqqAweR5U0JO1QslwFfh3sz/FM3G8UgYMf2atlT56eargCcbmr/AMRgBzyARRA5bxArSaABAAAAgAYAHQDpWZ+IlJcjnpAHTnFdM1USUXbKHAGY5QIP0wPLao2Xxo3OCJ9zT8G+iEmWInbl1+tdiRGoQTgDyNS6HJI3n9elEey3bvLSqqLIIVmGowNQPTz+tUFGQOtFeGCrfseIHQzDffxHb70MAv2R2jda01zvIIdVgImmNJOxBzRjgbhZAx3zMCBgnkMCgnY/DqLNxdc/tEMgEcmHOjXZy/sxnm3/AJGpS0NEm1gc6au4pUgwBpUqcGvWOQVMymIBjz3/ADrqnFAEehjIJx5b/wBqkRQBApV0KwBU9NT0Ac3GgE9AT/agKXO7tcVcKliO5tRInwBS4JHmSDHnVj4h7XWwkT42B084jmfUiB/asDf+ILjW2tsRpLlzjxknckznkdq4/JbfCOrBSVsq9s9t3Lzli0nYdAM+FB0oR4t5qdgpJKqDjbaPaojcM5EeVJvkG2+DpbkfrNWOG7RuWz+zdlncA+E+qnB9xVTVnOKcKs7iKKMTaNb2T8TXLShWtoUBmFHd5/6ce0CtZ2J28OJchFKqq5w2D5uPCR5YNZT4c+FLl+Ll4slrcCId/wCi+f0616JwvCpbQW7aBVGwH5+Z8zVIYbabNfkSScSl2wh7p9JZYGTqJwTDQGkDBP8AarCWdBRBhQMjf5RAbyOf51X7XcLbugn5kIUdScGPqKvKjaiTHQeQ5j6109nMPaWFA6ACmvojKVcAqw0sDsQcEGpao9sLc7tjbKSASwuLqVlAJKxIg7ZNDA8j4ns17V24imO7dlUzuA0Az6R96OcBxRNtVIEx688/yoHwLK5h20jqROenkK0FlbaiAQTt/Q/rpXnz2dMSZW+bp4fT9bVS4niu5vpdGPGpMc4wR7qSPpU4ETG0fr7j71T7YTXaPUQfcbx7TWLh2a9HpPEcVbQKzuqo0QzEAZGoZ54BrA/FXb5fiO64YhjABcZE5J0naBOT/SgPavbrXbFiyZHdhtRn5icJ9Fke9XPh/hAqXG/HEDyUifv/ACronO+CMY0G+xuG0p4nLMT4mJljAwOoA6Ul8TI3MTnrT9l31Xw6gWMYkeciOdSWxG66TmBmk6G7JSRVzst7YeyoQsxaEJOlSdXlPOqDn86I8LbIucNj5bjaukakNABjhu2kS3cudyiojorqSTMlhqn/AE5+tGLPEjRrC6VLRpWGAlgJE8szWd4HgyU4m2ySGdGBBVoh2gkTI3EUQ4YOtsoVbDY0rzBBlQDkeWIznNJJcDRfJoNJ6j6UqrWuOUgZYeRt3Mf9tNUxrBlPSinr1jkEBT0op4oAauhSinAoAQp6YCnrAB3afY1m+QbikkCAQxBjf0+1Bl+B+GKKrs5YFpdSFLSZAIIPy7D71qqQFK4L4bbMDxnwE65s3VbmFuDSfqJH2FAeP7G4q0ZuWW09VGtfUlZivXYpAVOWOLGU2jw5E1sEVcswUZiSSAAZ2ya9K7A+E7doK95Ua4NgB4F+o8beZwOXWr3bPwzY4lkZ9SlTnRC6h0bH33FGUQAADYCPpRDGlsJTsVLUNq6ioipblA8wCY8v61UQF9tW9a6DP42GCD4FLDSduk9dqMBpz1z9aocVY0yVUaXVbZ6iWjnyOr7VLwdwxpIiCQk81DQPoMRvgUvYFuuWH63rumatA8h7b7EuWbzqVABJa3p+Vkn5VnmJiNx571F2ewDRpyP1B/XOvTPijsv/ABHDui/Ovjtno67CeWoSvvXmNjiA37TZxAYHnyn12+9cmSNMtCVhm48AseYmfSJqvb4hHZlUziROx6/nQniOJc7sduuPoKI/DF/h1c98FDAeBmJgbgqRseRz0qMlSsquXQB4nhIuaRscjPLpR7hkUIASZKAkAxJmAKM9pX7JtwFRnnDKippg52zBiM7zQs8I0BwJAJBEiQImQDvBIPoaWM3KjJR9WXOB72IS2m8ZbSY3jFcvxFyQWtk4IGlgTymaudmDSRJJnz2Pi/pHvXAfGV0+vqM59KrQtj2nLDKlfI70Q4bSNBZyWW5MDJPiBAnrVENz6/XbFWwoUWzt+2/kp39qboU1HAJbm5C3QYGuCikHViATB8XlRPgbdsBlUsfEZ1xq1QpIkEyNoqn2cNV+6MxBO28P/ernDgS4/wBY/wDBaSa4Gi+S1qP71NXOg9RSqZSgTTgUopq9Y4zoCnikBTisAVICninrAGininpCssBAUop6VADRTxSpUAKKVKlQAqVKlQBxdTUpXGd5E451wliBpmRuD+KZmSetTUqAOEUiZafYD8q6Jp6agCJ3gen5bzXl/wATdld3xdwLhbgF1IGMzqXy8Qb6ivT7iwQeWx9/71kfjxALdq4RlWe2Tzhl1L91H1qOVWh4bMNxCARB3E/WqcSY51YuNMVL2Ilo3f2r6RiMwCZEgnliudulZVK3RxwNh5bPmecx/tWg4fihbAtvvo1ydySYI+wqfhzbZ3W0oECW0mV35E+tCu120XrTcirLnrP/APVTi7Y8o0g12a5c9AGBGMhQcD1JmrHEWhIO5mBJ6/oVF2baC4YyWE+ck/lXbtrC8oAPXJz9qs9E+xlbPn06VctI5QHAi5OcYgQc+9VHJBPPMfT9Gugkpr1fjUSc7g4+23nR0BsuGb9o7G+viU6fETEkHPTaKvcG3zEOrg6TIM50xGcjagPAiOLvqG/5bcuXhPKifZaHx+KCCvIdD1FTkMgj349felXA4VDkkk88D+lKpj2DkfJEzBH3E/zp2uAGOZOB7TVBuK0u0qdkwM5Yx6cquWUklzuRAE7D+tepZylgUhSpVooqemp6wBU9KlFACp6VKgBCnpUqAFSpRSigBUqelFADUop6esA5pRXVct+ulFgRXBIInOfryrNfHiA8G7Y3tsPXWo+sMfoa0wJkgRy+9Zf48EcE4PJrcdILjI+49qSb4Hjs80LYqGyknO3OkHxXfBqZiuZlDR9icNoAYcyUiPIw32pdu8OXUqNwQyfxD+u1FuyXU242O/nyqhxNi4VEZ6fUH+1Re7K9FnsRy4g7rE4GB18zy+tT8cxKJBIgkH2Y/wAiKAcBx7W+KCBYlgrROZ2+hj6mjl95ttEmHEY2Ljf08NWWkSZOlwIVdkLjJZREmQdpP7xB9q5UHuoAk61nnnScDyinG3p/P9GpRccW2ZSAJAIGxkYJnnigDT9nWz3zHussjjX4iW8IgST5DardgOGcQUJC8iMeMTnO3Sg3AcQ7cR3fePp7vUJYqZ7sNOPrRHs7iibjBizSsgkkmAYOPORSy0MthbTHL7/3pVT/AMQh3AnYzA2x1pVMoAEf9sfD4dKQYI2LGVDYAPOiiOSdsjAk4G07TNCrv+f4SMIIWcmGuch0jyopatupOq4CxE6dO3KFAO1eijlotKK6FcxsW9h5/wAzXYFaZQopwKQFPFACilFPSosKFFPFKKUUBQqVOBTxRYUNSp4pRWWFDUq6pqLChRSp6VZYUcE0q4uGI6bffH9K7JosKKz3RbDs2EUST0AGT6YNeafGPbdviXGgOUUaRqlVJOS2nkeWc45V6Jx9jvLd23mXtsoggHZhicdN68b4y1ctt3VxSrAyQwg5/X51Od6HiM/DrGAf1yqfsxAD5xVO2zLImiPZVrVJ8tv6VBjoMdl8SF+YwB9gJFE+HvqbaRtArOXfDrB2n7czRfgLf7NCDggR/wDGptFECbfDf8XrzI7tl6fMqkHqPENulH77QrjwjK4GMAwfpP3oFxPFd3xdsn5SsGdgC249CoPtRfjby5MyJHtJxJ2j3p1/qT7LBMT0j8j/AL1RucUb3gtsURdOttyzCflwYGaH8X2k1wm2pAUtE8yo3Mb9ftRfgu7RdIUlYyDgHGKYwP8AC2QLiOWJm3pgj/24GZ/lRDglIuEFsAKJ2xMHO2MH2NCR2gyugFtPlW4CPEYKmNtxvjz50Zt8el06RbVRoIaDvkeEg++fOkkMi5eJDEaufOOeaVVLlm/PhVCMQS4kiMTT0lFCoyjv3x+G3/43KudmZknJ2k5MScTSpV6C2cpZt7/9I/OpqVKtYCFOKVKtAVOKVKsYCFPSpVhohT0qVYAqVKlQAhSpUqDGPSpUq00jvfKfQ09KlWGFM/P9PzoZ8T8LbdSzW1ZhauQSoJHhGxO1KlWPRp5NY5+g/nRLsXf/AKT+dKlXNIotlvj/AMf8DflRTs7/ACk9B/40qVTZRGd+JPw+hq+n+Un8IpUqaOhOyv2bvd/hH5ijV7/JP8K/zpUqYxlrs5j3yZ/5a/8A6zWh4H5v+r/7rSpUrN7CF75jSpUqwof/2Q=="
          alt="Спил дерева с Авто вышки">
      </div>
      <div class="variant__title">Спил дерева с Авто вышки</div>
      <div class="variant__text">Данный способ позволяет удалить дерево или ветки там, где использование автовышки невозможно. Арбарист оснащен специальным снаряжением, которое позволяет ему быстро залезть к необходимому месту среза ствола или ветки.</div>
      <a href="/">Подробнее</a>
    </div>

    <div class="variant-right">
      <div class="variant-right-1"></div>
      <div class="foto">
        <img src="https://65.img.avito.st/image/1/1.8O2zvba6XASFFJ4B34q0yFoeWgAHnlTGAh5YDA8WXg.MmcQ850dtMPiU2LpsyrLO_qXCTBSkeQ7L3JfW6YHRFo" alt="Спил дерева альпинистами">
      </div>
      <div class="variant__title">Спил дерева альпинистом</div>
      <div class="variant__text">Данный способ позволяет удалить дерево или ветки там, где использование автовышки невозможно. Арбарист оснащен специальным снаряжением, которое позволяет ему быстро залезть к необходимому месту среза ствола или ветки.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Тоже вариант.